# Blender to Unity missing faces

Tags: faces, normals, unity

I have a problem with missing faces. I made a blender model and it looks great. put it in Unity and it has holes in it. I found that is could be a normals problem so I looked up the orientation in blender but they are facing the right way. what else can it be?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The "missing faces" are in places where you have Ngons, Try triangulating your model in Blender before exporting to Unity. Edit mode > Select everthing > Face menu > Triangulate faces.  ( Ctrl + T )

Comment: thank you that worked :D